# Laravel Validation on Lang file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.8 and I included a validation.php on my resource/lang/xx/ folder.

Into my controller I use this code to validing fields:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'birthplace_id' => 'required',
            'birthdate' => 'required',
            'fiscal_code' => 'required|unique:customers,fiscal_code,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
        ]);
```

I don't need to return the $validator but I need, in the same function, print the errors.
I wrote this code:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
                \Log::info(json_encode($validator));
}
```

And I got this:

```
{
        "customMessages": [],
        "fallbackMessages": [],
        "customAttributes": [],
        "customValues": [],
        "extensions": [],
        "replacers": []
}
```

this is the content of my validation.php file:

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines contain the default error messages used by
| the validator class. Some of these rules have multiple versions such
| as the size rules. Feel free to tweak each of these messages here.
|
*/

'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
'unique' => 'Il :attribute è già stato utilizzato.',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/

'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Attributes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used to swap our attribute placeholder
| with something more reader friendly such as "E-Mail Address" instead
| of "email". This simply helps us make our message more expressive.
|
*/

'attributes' => [],

];
```

How can I connect my validator to validation.php lang file?

Comment: Edit please your question with one of validation.php content screenshot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this code:

```
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'description' => 'Validation failed',
                'errors' => $validator->messages()
            ], 500);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically connect to the validation.php file

Try using it this way:

```
$request->validate([
   'lastname' => 'required',
   'firstname' => 'required',
    'gender' => 'required',
    'birthplace_id' => 'required',
    'birthdate' => 'required',
    'fiscal_code' => 'required|unique:customers,fiscal_code,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL'
]);
```

Comment: In this way how can I test if it fails or not?

Comment: The controller returns an array of errors to the view. You can call it in the view with $errors->all()
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: I tried your code but I got error:

`$request->validate([
                'lastname' => 'required',
                'firstname' => 'required',
                'fiscal_code' => 'required|unique:customers,fiscal_code,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
            ]);
            
            if ($errors->any()) {
                \Log::error($errors->all());
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You should call validate on the request like this:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
       'lastname' => 'required',
       'firstname' => 'required',
       'gender' => 'required',
       'birthplace_id' => 'required',
       'birthdate' => 'required',
       'fiscal_code' => 'required|unique:customers,fiscal_code,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',          
    ]);
```

You can access the error messages in your `blade` as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

You can print them out like this:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

If for example, `fiscal_code` is not unique the message

> Il fiscal_code è già stato utilizzato.

should appear.

Comment: Could I not use the validator errors on my controller? It is a function for API and it doesn't return a view with blade...